# How to find all files of type and move them to a {another_dir}/{dir_files_are_at}/{file}?

Tags: linux, bash, find

I have a bunch of directories with a bunch of files in them and a text file. It looks like this

```
MainDir
|------dir1
|       |-------file1
|       |-------file2
|       |-------file3.txt
|------dir17
|       |-------file23
|       |-------file34
|       |-------file52.txt
|       |-------file65
```

Number of files in each dir is random and only 1 or none txt file.
I need to move all txt files to "txtFiles" dir inside MainDir and every txt file needs to be in a subdir with the same name as the dir it came from (the subdirs in txtFiles dir does not exist so they need to be created). This is how it should look line

```
MainDir
|------dir1
|       |-------file1
|       |-------file2
|------dir17
|       |-------file23
|       |-------file34
|       |-------file65
|------txtFiles
|       |-------dir1
|       |        |-------file3.txt
|       |-------dir17
|       |        |-------file52.txt
```

Is there way to do it with one find command?

**Also some of the files and dirs names have whitespaces in them!!!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ tree
.
`-- MainDir
    |-- dir1
    |   |-- notes.txt
    |   |-- some_file-1
    |   |-- some_file-2
    |   `-- some_file-3
    `-- dir17
        |-- README.txt
        |-- some_file-1
        |-- some_file-2
        `-- some_file-3

3 directories, 8 files
```

Using `rsync`:

```
$ rsync -a --include '*.txt' --exclude '*/*' MainDir/ MainDir/txtFiles/
$ tree
.
`-- MainDir
    |-- dir1
    |   |-- notes.txt
    |   |-- some_file-1
    |   |-- some_file-2
    |   `-- some_file-3
    |-- dir17
    |   |-- README.txt
    |   |-- some_file-1
    |   |-- some_file-2
    |   `-- some_file-3
    `-- txtFiles
        |-- dir1
        |   `-- notes.txt
        `-- dir17
            `-- README.txt

6 directories, 10 files
```

The command uses `--include '*.txt'` to include all files with `.txt` file name suffix, and `--exclude '*/*'` to exclude other files. By using `-a` or `--archive`, a copy of the part of the source hierarchy that is copied is created at the destination.

Running this again would result in an empty `MainDir/txtFiles/txtFiles` directory being created.  Adding `-m` or `--prune-empty-dirs` to the `rsync` invocation would avoid that.

---

Using `find` (from within `MainDir`):

```
$ find . -type f -name '*.txt' ! -path '*/txtFiles/*' \
    -exec sh -c 'for n; do
                     d="txtFiles/${n%/*}";
                     mkdir -p "$d" && cp "$n" "$d"
                 done' sh {} +
```

This finds all regular files whose names matches `*.txt` and that are not in a `txtFiles` directory.

For each found filename path, the directory part of the path is created under `txtFiles` and the file is copied there.

The only difference between the `rsync` approach and this is that `rsync` may copy non-regular files that matches the given name (directories named pipes etc.), and that the `find` command *must* be run from within `MainDir`.